# How do I bind an action parameter to an object stored in session scope in Spring MVC 3.x?

Tags: session, spring-mvc, model-binding

I would like to do something like this:

```
public ModelAndView someAction(SessionUser sessionUser, Model model) {

    model.addAttribute(sessionUser);

    return new ModelAndView("someview");

}
```

Where an instance of the SessionUser object is stored in the Session and is bound to the sessionUser parameter during the execution of the request.

I'm new to Spring MVC, but in .NET MVC this could be accomplished by creating a ModelBinder as such:

```
public class SessionUserModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    private const string sessionUserSessionKey = "_sessionUser";

    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Return the sessionUser from Session[] (creating it first if necessary)
        SessionUser sessionUser = (SessionUser)controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionUserSessionKey];
        if (sessionUser == null)
        {
            sessionUser = new SessionUser();
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Session[sessionUserSessionKey] = sessionUser;
        }
        return sessionUser;
    }
}
```

This would be executed as part of the request execution pipeline. If sessionUser wasn't found in the Request parameters, it would give this custom model binder a shot.

Is there a similar mechanism in Spring MVC 3 that would allow me to accomplish the same thing? I would prefer that my controller and its methods not know whether the bound object comes from form fields, url parameters, the session, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can declaratively bind a model attribute to the session. In order to do that you need to annotate your controller with `@SessionAttributes("sessionUser")`.

**See also:**

- [15.3.2.9 Specifying attributes to store in a session with @SessionAttributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-sessionattrib)

Comment: Thanks for your response... In the code above, I am able to determine if a sessionUser exists in Session scope. If it exists, I return it. If it doesn't, I instantiate a new one. 

Is it possible to accomplish this using @SessionAttributes?

Comment: @Jason Stonebraker: You can try to create a `@ModelAttribute`-annotated method to create a new `SessionUser`. As far as I understand, it will be used when `SessionUser` doesn't exist in the session.